# Mudar tamanho da font do pickerview

Tags: swift, datepicker, swift-3

Boa tarde. 09/05/2017 
Tenho o seguinte pickerview:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como podem perceber logo o primeiro item das duas lista não aparece o nome todo.
Acho que devido ao tamanho.
Do lado Esquerdo o nome completo é : "CERVEJA DA BOA"
Do lado Direito seus itens são : "CERVEJA DA BOA 01", "CERVEJA DA BOA 02"
**Gostaria de saber se tem como alterar o tamanho da fonte do pickerview ou se tem como toda a descrição dos itens ficarem visiveis**.
Tentei utilizar o código abaixo, mas apesar de alterar o COR da font, não altera o tamanho da mesma.

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, attributedTitleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> NSAttributedString?
    {// MUDA A COR DAS LINHAS
        var myTitle = NSAttributedString();
        if component == 0
        {
        let titleData = vLocal[row] as! Bebida_Class;

        myTitle = NSAttributedString(string: titleData.bebida_descricao,
                                     attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Georgia", size: 10.0)!,
                                     NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.blue])
        }
        if component == 1
        {   
           etc....         
        }
        return myTitle
    }
```

Desde já agradeço a atenção de todos..
ps1 : Caso alguém edit este post, por favor NÃO tire palavras, pois as mesmas, incluindo o agradecimento, são para formar um todo.

Answer (score 1):

Nesse caso é melhor usar o seguinte método  do UIPickerViewDelegate:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
    var pickerLabel = view as? UILabel

    if (pickerLabel == nil){
        pickerLabel = UILabel()
        pickerLabel!.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    }
    if component == 0 {
        pickerLabel!.text = cervejas[row]
    }else {
        pickerLabel!.text = descricao[row]
    }

    return pickerLabel!
}
```

Observe que você retorna uma instancia de UILabel então pode mudar a fonte da forma como quiser usando  a propriedade *pickerLabel!.attributedText*, caso precise alterar a largura de cada Component use o seguinte método do delegate:

```
  func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, widthForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat {
     if component == 0 {
        return 50
     }else {
        return 100
     }
 }
```

Comment: Boa tarde Edson <br>
Como sempre digo para todos, tem que se perguntar a quem SABE :) <br>
**Perfeita sua resposta**.. Agora consigo ver todos os itens do lado esquerdo e direito...<br>
Cara, quando coloquei o código e ate consegui mudar a cor..fala serio.. me senti mui MACHO :)<br>
Meu nivel na programação de swift é EASE-BEBECHORÃO... Ainda tenho muito tempo pela frente. <br>
Meu muito obrigado pela sua ajuda :)
Abraços

Comment: Rsrsrsrs, quando estamos aprendendo é assim mesmo, ninguém nasce sabendo nada, mas com o tempo e a medida que for precisando usar as coisas vai apreendendo.